# Insert values into arbitrary 2d coordinate numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy matrix:

```
input = np.array([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
])
```

I want to add an extra element to each row at a specific location. For example after coordinate (0, 0) add 100, after (1,1) add 101 and after (0, 2) add 102 so my final will look like this:

```
output = np.array([
  [1, 100,   2, 3],
  [4,   5, 101, 6],
  [7, 102,   8, 9]
])
```

How would you do this?

Comment: Will there always be one element per row? There must be, otherwise the resulting array would not be rectangular - what do you want to pad with in this case? If they are all on different rows, why not let the input be a list of columns to insert elements after, as there would be no need for a row index if there is one per row...

Comment: Yes, there will always be equal elements per row, but it won't always be one element. For example there could be 2 insertions or 3 per row. Each row will always have the same number of insertions.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're going to rely on `insert` a lot in your code. This really is not efficient work in numpy at all. Why can't you do all this in python and convert to an array after? Not only would it be easier to code (than, say, using `ravel()`, keeping track of indices in 1D, and then reshaping) but probably faster

Comment: `Each row will always have the same number of insertions`. Will these insertions be contiguous, or will you need to insert a value at position 1 & another at position 4?

Comment: Insertions will not be continuous. You could insert a value after position one and four in the same row.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new array with a new size and replace the items based on the intended indices:

```
In [15]: arr = np.zeros((3, 4))

In [16]: ind = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]

In [17]: arr[ind] = [100, 101, 102]

In [18]: arr[np.where(arr==0)] = input.ravel()

In [19]: arr
Out[19]: 
array([[   1.,  100.,    2.,    3.],
       [   4.,    5.,  101.,    6.],
       [   7.,  102.,    8.,    9.]])
```

Note that instead of using `np.where()` and a direct indexing you could use `np.place()` too (in case you needed a functional approach).

```
np.place(arr, arr==0, input.ravel())
```

Comment: And I'm glad you did! You've used `ravel()` the opposite way around than I saw in an answer way back when I wanted something similar (convert whole thing to 1D and then try scale the insertion points based on `shape` and the row wanted, then `reshape`)  and this is _much_ cleaner :) I didn't realise that such an approach as this was possible.

Comment: @roganjosh Yup, and even a more cleaner way might be using `np.place` with the same principal.

Answer (score 0):

In numpy you can also specify the "axis";  axis 0 is running vertically downwards across rows, axis 1 is running horizontally across columns. This does not help if you want to add an element to only one row or one column, though. In both cases you could use np.insert().

For example:
np.insert(output, 1, 2) gives the output
[(1, 2, 100, 2, 3, 4, 5, 101, 6, 7, 102, 8, 9)]

as (like Joe remarked) the shape of the array is "destroyed" if you add an element to only one row and not the others. There the element 2 is added at the first index (numbering starts at 0).

An alternative would be
np.insert(a, 1, 3, axis=1)

Then a 3 would be inserted to every row at the first index (with again the first element of each row being of zero index by default). Effectively a column containing only 3s is added as second column (=index of 1).

You could also preallocate an empty array, that is np.zeros(#desired size at the end) for the desired resulting array and set this array at the desired positions to the elements you want to insert at those position.
For example
emptyarray=np.zeros(4,4)
emptyarray[1,4]=10 
if you want to have a 10 at row 1 and column 4 of the desired array.

Then you could use a for loop to fill the zero-elements with the elements your 'old' array...combine it with an if statement to change only elements that are zero. This has the advantage, that you have total control of the resulting dimension of the array without getting error messages. The disadvantage is, that if you insert only one element both row and column index of the previous elements might change. So you really have to be clear about the dimension you want your resulting array to have.

Answer (score 0):

first form a 3x4 array of 0s

```
a1 = np.zeros(3,4)
```

so a1 will be: `array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])`
replace your given co-ordinate with required values, first array represents axis and second one represents respective element of that array. so these elements will be replace with provided element in RHS:

```
    a1[[0,1,2],[1,2,1]]=[100,101,102]
```

Now replace remaining 0s at other location with  respective values in iuput array:

```
    a1[np.where(a1==0)] = input.ravel()
```

output:`array([[   1.,  100.,    2.,    3.],
       [   4.,    5.,  101.,    6.],
       [   7.,  102.,    8.,    9.]])`

Comment: This is identical to the approach given by @Kasramvd 40 minutes ago.